# Time-series linear combination that fits a given time-series

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, finance

Given N different time-series and a new time-series for the same time period, what would be the correct approach to finding a linear combination of the N time-series which best describes the new time-series?

*I'm new to the field so this might be a simple question with a simple answer, I just want to be sure I'm in the right direction for further reading.

Comment: It all depends on what you mean by "best describes".  As it stands, if we were to drop the term "time series" and just view your data as vectors, it would sound like a routine least squares fit.  How does your problem differ from that?

Comment: @whuber assuming "best describes" means "least squares", then would you say that this is a multivariate linear regression with N variables (vectors)?

Comment: Yes, that's what it sounds like.

Comment: thanks @whuber, your suggestion to view the time-series as plain vectors helps.
How would you define "best describes" if we want to consider a time-series that changes twice as fast as one of the base N time-series as "described" by that time-series. lease-squares would not work here. In this case, should we transform the N time-series to their respective rate-of-change vectors and run a regression on them?

Comment: You have to decide whether variable transformations are allowed. If not, then you are left with least squares on the original regressors. If yes, then you would have to figure out the relevant transformations first and then do least squares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Multiple Linear Regression, on the log-returns of the time series. 
In the content of time-series of asset returns, a key note on using the intercept:
 - if the goal is to fit an assets return using a set of other assets for purposes of portfolio construction, than an intercept should be avoided as it provides an external sources of "free" baseline return (a bias in the linear regression) which is not achievable using any of the given assets.
 - if the goal is to create the best possible fit, then the intercept should be used and it will provide a better fit (or at least no worse) then without the intercept.

These are probably very basic concepts, but it took me a while to get a clear grip of the solution so I'm adding my answer.